# Bind K8s ingress/load balancer to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

When I run a local cluster using Docker for Window's built-in Kubernetes server, and install the Nginx ingress, the server is accessible on the entire local network. How can I bind the server to the loopback address (127.0.0.1) only so that it is not accessible?

I tried setting the Nginx's LoadBalancer service's `loadBalancerIp` to `127.0.0.1` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by switching to Kind (instead of Docker Desktop's K8s). It allows specifying `listenAddress=127.0.0.1` when creating a cluster.